# How to compile and execute new apache storm scheduler code?

Tags: java, compilation, scheduler, apache-storm, execute

I've modified existing Even Scheduler code in Apache Storm. Later how do I compile and execute this scheduler on a benchmark program and check if there are any changes in metrics? 
What config files have to be changed? 
Please provide some helpful documents with step-by-step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a step by step article here https://inside.edited.com/taking-control-of-your-apache-storm-cluster-with-tag-aware-scheduling-b60aaaa5e37e.

Relevant part:

> To wrap things up, we should also cover how the class is meant to be
>   actually used by Storm. There are two things we need to do for that:
>
> - Instruct storm to use our scheduler instead of its default scheduler, via config.
> - Package our class in a .jar file and add it to the $STORM_HOME/lib directory for Storm to be able to access it.
>
> The config necessary is again very simple; similarly to the tag
>   scheduling metadata, we just have to add this line to
>   $STORM_HOME/conf/storm.yaml(and make sure the nimbus process is
>   restarted):
>
> storm.scheduler: com.edited.tagawarescheduler.TagAwareScheduler